# How to change the look of a UserControl dynamically in Blend?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I'm new to Blend and XAML, and I've got a UserControl containing just a white rounded off rectangle and a label with black text. However, when the UserControl is clicked, I want the rectangle to change to Blue and the label text to White, to emulate a sort of selected look. What is the best way to do this? I'm not familiar with XAML so I was hoping there'd be a solution where I can just set two templates for it in Blend, and then in that UserControl code window, have a click event handler where I just tell it to switch over to the other template. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest - and designer friendliest - way to achieve this is to [define two visual states](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjihfevi-_PAhUYM8AKHWBYCqQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fee371169(v%3Dexpression.40).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFVQyrMD2jNWXA7OD5_vIhBvvosxg&sig2=TBjhEZHxU1EoCTijZpCfsg&bvm=bv.136593572,d.bGg). When the user clicks the control you can [use the GotoStateAction](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjihfevi-_PAhUYM8AKHWBYCqQQFggpMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Fexpression%2F2010%2F02%2F22%2Fswitching-visual-states-easily-using-gotostateaction%2F&usg=AFQjCNEtHuCsmB0S1zsWFHLiWw7VOkwGWg&sig2=N4e58yi0AjBF-iMcNd26MA&bvm=bv.136593572,d.bGg) to switch between the states.

Using visual states allows you to define everything visually without having to delve into code or XAML.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much. You're right - it's very visual. And it helps to then see what XAML it produces.